# passing list of strings in efficient way

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void function1(const char** keywords) {  // C like
    for (const char** keyword = keywords; *keyword; ++keyword) {
        std::cout << *keyword << std::endl;
    }
}

void function2(const std::vector<std::string>& keywords) {  // C++11 like
    for(const std::string& keyword : keywords) {
        std::cout << keyword << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    static const char* keywords[] = { "hello", "world", "!", 0 };
    function1(keywords);
    function2({ "hello", "world", "!" });
    return 0;
}
```

Both functions do the same result. I like the new c++11 format of initialization where values are inline and I can skip empty value (zero). The issue is a performance. I expect that function2 will dynamically alocate memory on each invoke. I suppose it wan't be efficient. Is there a better way to implement such function with c++ manner keeping old C efficency?

Update:

There is a little misunderstanding. My concern is usage of std::vector which provokes dynamic memory allocation. In fact I would use std::string in the body of function1 so std::string allocation is not a case. The same std::cout was added by me as an example of usage (not a real case). std::array cannot be used here becouse length of list is not fixed.

I extend my question:
Goal is use only one argument with default empty value to pass list of strings. How to achieve this in most effient and pretty-look way?

So above functions' declarations may look as follows:

```
void function1(const char** keywords = nullptr)

void function2(const std::vector<std::string>& keywords = {})
```

Here I see the next problem. Invoking function1 without parameter cost nothing but I expect empty vector initialization in function2. Am I right?

Comment: There is no dynamic allocation in `function2`.

Comment: @Galik But there is in constructing the argument. The vector internal buffer. And probably the strings, depending on implementation.

Comment: When printing a set of strings to `std::cout` - or any physical stream, such as a file on disk - performance is a minor concern.   The latency of I/O will be significantly larger than any potential performance gain you can achieve in how arguments are constructed to be passed to functions, or the loop itself.   Read up on the concept of "premature optimisation".

Comment: @juanchopanza All the compiler needs is out there, the amount of the elements as well as string content. So it can even be treated as a global [3] element array of const chars*

Comment: @juanchopanza But none of that is happening in `fuction2`. You could just as well call that function with a pre-constructed vector. Which is the more likely scenario in real code.

Comment: @juanchopanza we can change this example to avoid copying the strings, `using namespace std::literals; function2({ "hello"s, "world"s, "!"s });`. In C++20 we can have `constexpr std::vector<std::string> keywords{ "hello"s, "world"s, "!"s };`

Comment: `void function3(std::initializer_list<std::string_view> keywords)` to avoid allocation. (but `string_view` is C++17)

Comment: Don't bother with it, you're limited by io here.

Comment: So many comments and answers on what signature would best fit this particular way of calling `function2`. But what does your real-world use case look like? Do you already have a `vector<string>`? Then a `vector<string_view>` argument is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your responses. Based @Jarod42 response I implemented my own similar one.

```
template <typename StringContainer = std::initializer_list<const char*>>
void function(const StringContainer& keywords = {}) {
    if (!keywords.size()) {
        return;
    }
    for (const auto& keyword : keywords) {
        std::cout << keyword << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    function();
    function({ "hello", "world", "!" });
    std::vector<std::string> keys = { "hello", "world", "!" };
    function(keys);
    return 0; 
}
```

I will appreciate all comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that C and C++ compilers are now *optimizing* compilers... As both function have the same observable result, and as this can be guessed at compile time, a compiler is free to implement `function2` the same as function 1 by inlining it.

Even if it does not inline the function, the vector could be prepared at compile time, saving a lot of boiler plate construction.

But you then fall on the dark part in you want to use the code on more that one system: you cannot make sure the way a specific compiler will translate it.

So you fall on the usual rule for low level optimization: it does not really make sense of a language point of view, but only for a specific implementation with a specific configuration (compilation and linking options). And then the only reliable way are assembly code reading and benchmarking for different versions of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If there is choice for C++17
there is new class [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)  that is exactly what you want.

```
void function2(const std::vector<std::string_view>& keywords) {  // C++17 
    for(auto const& keyword : keywords) {
        std::cout << keyword << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient if the OP already has a `vector<string>`.

Comment: Whenever I see a `std::vector<T> const&`, I wonder why it's not a `std::span<T>`.

Comment: @Deduplicator I haven't know std::span class(C++20). thanks for comments

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 difficulties:
`const char*` versus `std::string` (or even `std::string_view` in C++17)

and the collection of the above type.

as `Container<const char*>`, `Container<std::string>` and `Container<std::string_view>` are different types which will require conversion to pass from one to another.

To avoid those difficulties, you might use template:

```
template <typename StringContainer>
void function3(const StringContainer& keywords) {
    for(const auto& keyword : keywords) {
        std::cout << keyword << std::endl;
    }
}
```

but you cannot then use

```
function3({ "hello", "world", "!" });
```

as `{/*..*/}` has no type. It can though match C-array or `initializer_list` template.

So, you might add extra overload to handle that case:

```
template <typename String>
void function3(std::initializer_list<String> keywords) {
    return function3<std::initializer_list<String>>(keywords);
}
```

and to handle empty `initializer_list`, or default argument, you might do:

```
template <typename String = std::string>
void function3(std::initializer_list<String> keywords = {}) {
    return function3<std::initializer_list<String>>(keywords);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/diixV-)